# Determine Array Key For Field Type Programatically

Tags: entities

Different fields have different keys for the actual 'value' of the field. For example a regular text field has:

```
$node->field_my_text_field[$node->language]['value']
```

Whereas if I have a field using the email module, it looks like this:

```
$node->field_my_email_field[$node->language]['email']
```

I'm working on a function that saves a whole bunch of fields, and I want it to be as flexible as possible, it has a loop that looks like this:

```
foreach($person_details as $k=>$detail) {
    $node->{'field_'.$k}[$node->language][0]['value'] = $detail;
}
```

This is no good at the moment since 'value' is hard coded, and I have some fields in there that use 'email' and a few others from various modules.

Is there any way to know in advance what the key should be?

Comment: Many fields have more than one data column (image field for example), have you you thought about how you're going to handle those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution ended up being this:

```
$field_structure = field_info_field($field_name);
$keys = array_keys($field_structure['storage']['details']['sql']['FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT']['field_data_'.$field_name]);
```

This gives an array of all the posible data columns for $field_name, where $field_name is something like 'field_my_field'.